# Is there any way to get the daily availability of the items listed by an ebay seller account?

Tags: rest, ebay-api

I need to put together a pipeline that gathers the daily availability of items listed by an ebay seller account. Unfortunately, this metric isn't included in the analytics api, and the only lead I have is the GetSellerList endpoint (https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/guides/features-guide/default.html#development/items-retrieving.html), for which I have no idea what the url is because it's not mentioned anywhere in the documentation.

Is there any other, more convenient way to get a seller's listed items' daily availability, or if not does anyone have an example a request that calls this GetSellerList  endpoint?

Any help would me much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

GetSellerList Works only with your items.

If you want the list of items of another seller the easiest solution is to use finding API with proper parameters to get list of the items.

But if seller has more than 10K items you have to add some filter, for example StartTime and EndTime in way to reduce the output under 10K items that is the maximum (100 Items × 100 pages)

Then, if you want more info about items, you have to call GetItem for each item

Comment: do you have link to the endpoint in this finding api? I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: These are the APIs: https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/CallRef/index.html. use the one that better fits your needs